# Is it possible to use generic method without passing the type in parameters in java

Tags: java, generics

Problem:

I want to create a generic function which will return me strogly typed object.

Function :

```
public <T > T GetPet(AnimalKingdom allAnimals,int id) {
    return (T) allAnimals.getAnimalsManager().findAnimalById(id);

}
```

The above function will return a strongly typed object or throw error.

Usage :

```
GetPet<Tiger>(thisZoo,tigersId).Roar();
```

Coming from C# background. Googled for the same but was not able to find a solution, it seems that I need to pass the generic type in function for it to work.

How can the above scenario implemented in java.

Comment: I'm not sure if you were just trying to come up with an example of something, or if that's what you're actually trying to do? How could you guarantee that that `int` id actually matched an object of type `Tiger` ? Or you mean you want it to throw an error if it's not?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You post a code sample and ask how to write that code sample ...? Is your code sample supposed to be C# and you are asking for the Java equivalent? Or have you tried compiling this as Java code and been surprised by a compilation error?

Comment: All you have shown is a fancy, overly-complicated method of casting an `Animal` to a `Tiger`. And its not even type safe. Are you trying to accomplish more than is shown here?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Was on vacation. Yes I am from C# background. Was looking for syntax or way to implement above. @cambecc has given the right reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, you explicitly specify the type arguments of the generic method before the method name. For example:

```
class Example {
    public static <T> T getPet(AnimalKingdom allAnimals, int id) {
        return (T)allAnimals.getAnimalsManager().findAnimalById(id);
    }
}
```

Then to invoke:

```
Example.<Tiger>getPet(thisZoo, tigersId).roar();
```

Alternatively, you can use [type inferencing](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic7):

```
Tiger tiger = Example.getPet(thisZoo, tigersId);
tiger.roar();
```

By the way, your `getPet` method is not very safe because there is no runtime check performed to ensure the object returned is actually an instance of `Tiger`. In fact, the Java compiler gives a warning on this line:

```
return (T)allAnimals.getAnimalsManager().findAnimalById(id);
```

The reason is because the cast to `(T)` is unchecked due to [type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3).

To strengthen your code, I suggest the following change:

```
class Example {
    public static <T> T getPet(Class<T> clazz, AnimalKingdom allAnimals, int id) {
        return clazz.cast(allAnimals.getAnimalsManager().findAnimalById(id));
    }
}
```

Then to invoke:

```
Example.getPet(Tiger.class, thisZoo, tigersId).roar();
```

The benefit of passing in the class object (`Tiger.class`) is that:

1. It provides the compiler the type to use for `<T>` (again via type inferencing).
2. You can add your own explicit runtime type check by calling the `Class.cast` method. The Java compiler warning goes away, and type safety is restored. For example, if `findAnimalById` mistakenly returns an instance of Bear when you expected Tiger, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

please try something like

```
Tiger tiger = GetPet(thisZoo,tigersId);
tiger.Roar();
```

Comment: It will work but, I dont want to add extra variable declaration.
As the example given is just a sample. But the actual code would be something simmilar to logging which is used multiple times in the code. So at so many places I need to define variable.

Comment: please see the other answers, as they explain generics here is not solving anything. Above 2 line of code will have no bad effect compared to other in runtime. This just allows compiler to infer type.

Answer (score 0):

Using a generic is simply the wrong choice here. You should take a look at inheritance, virtual function, abtract classes and interface.

Answer (score 0):

As SylvainL said, generics is not the right choice here. This looks like a simple inheritance / interface problem to me.

**New getPet method:**

```
public Animal getPet(AnimalKingdom allAnimals, int id)
{
    return allAnimals.getAnimalsManager().findAnimalById(id);
}
```

**Using inheritance:**

```
class Animal { void Roar() { throw new Exception("This animal cannot roar!"); } };
class Tiger extends Animal { @Override void Roar() { ... }; ... };
```

Usage:

```
getPet(thisZoo, tigersId).Roar();
```

**OR Using an interface:** (a little more complicated but probably generally better)

Note: you don't really need Animal in this case, you can just use Object

```
class Animal { ... }; // no Roar method
interface Roarer { void Roar(); };
class Tiger extends Animal implements Roarer { @Override void Roar() { ... }; ... };
```

Note: You can stick either of the below usages into a method to just end up with something like:

```
roar(getPet(thisZoo, tigersId));
```

Usage: (you can remove the `try {} catch`, but this is generally not a good idea)

```
try
{
   ((Roarer)getPet(thisZoo, tigersId)).Roar();
}
catch (ClassCastException e) { /* handle error */ };
```

Usage alternative: (to safely avoid `try {} catch`, haven't tried this yet, but I think it might work)

```
Animal animal = getPet(thisZoo, tigersId);
if (Roarer.class.isAssignableFrom(animal.class))
   ((Roarer)animal).Roar();
else
   // handle error
```